# How to change Materialize CSS tab underline color?

Tags: css, materialize

I am not able to change the underline color of tabs in Materialize CSS.
Here is a sample image with underlining in the default color; I want to make it black:
[image: sample image].

And this is sample code I am using:

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col s12">
    <ul class="tabs">
      <li class="tab col s3"><a href="#test1">Test 1</a></li>
      <li class="tab col s3"><a class="active" href="#test2">Test 2</a></li>
      <li class="tab col s3 disabled"><a href="#test3">Disabled Tab</a></li>
      <li class="tab col s3"><a href="#test4">Test 4</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="test1" class="col s12">Test 1</div>
  <div id="test2" class="col s12">Test 2</div>
  <div id="test3" class="col s12">Test 3</div>
  <div id="test4" class="col s12">Test 4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: your code have not display any tab view share proper code

Comment: What's the CSS you've used to make it works?

Comment: give my answer a try

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make Use of this

CSS

```
 .tabs .indicator{
    background-color:red;/*your color*/
    }
```